# External CSS link not working

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cpanel

I've looked all over for a solution but the external link for "gencustomfont" will not work, yes everything is named correctly. Though if I put the bare code in it will, but I'd feel better if it was less cluttered once I officially start adding styles. I'm using c panel.

MAIN

```
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/gencustomfont.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">



  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>We are making magic!</h1>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>';

?>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #FF7878;
  background-color: #000;
}
</style>
```

As can you see I'm trying to override the bootstrap css with my own. I don't have the time to use "Less".

Comment: give the full path of that css file in your code `<link href = 'full path of css file'`.

Comment: what exactly won't work? do you get a 404 error missing resource or do you code and you are not able to see fonts? Does the genCustomfont.css exist in the same folder as bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: are your style tag also in the css custom file? if yes then you probably found your error

Comment: Before I started adding my own css, I tested the link by changing the color of the font, to see if it will override it . The color does not change, meaning anything else I put in will not change either.

Comment: Yes Coding Enthusiast, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.css` file, you do not need to put `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>`. These are only needed in the HTML file!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it'd be so simple!